# Do I need to create another connection for client side Mongo DB in React Next.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

So, I have followed [with-mongodb](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb) github example and the article from [official mongodb website](https://developer.mongodb.com/how-to/nextjs-with-mongodb/) that is about this repo. I successfully connect with DB client and I am able to read the data from DB with getServerSideProps and getStaticProps.

But I am having issue using the already made DB connection inside components (for example using insert function) because Node.js code can be used only in `/pages` directory and it doesn't work in `/components` directory.

So, what's the better approach for Next.js? Use MongoDB Realm SDK or create API endpoints in `/pages`? Can anyone please give me short example of such API endpoint with some very simple example of insert function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I finally understand it. I am using /api/* paths as bridge between mongo and next and using axios calls on front ends to retrieve those data.

I first thought I will have to use Mongo Realm's authentication but building my own users DB with hashed passwords wasn't that hard.